# How to show the separator in DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle with a transparent background?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid in my WPF Project, and I'm trying to customize the look of the headers.
Specifically, I want a transparent background with a white separator.

However, if I set the background to `Transparent` the separators disappear with it.

This is my style:

```
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="White"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

What am I doing wrong?